# Save Quote custom data and read it again

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-options, quote

I store my custom data in my ajax CartController issuing:

```
foreach ( $quote->getAllItems() as $item ) {
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
    $item->setMyCustomData( 'OK' );
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice( 777 );
    $item->save();
}
```

and I want to read these data again in my Order/Pdf/Invoice.php:

```
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
    Mage::log($item->getOrderItem()->getData()); // Here I wish to see my data set previously
}
```

The problem is I can only see the price update, but I can **not** see my `MyCustomData` field. So I suppose that my custom data stored just as `protected _data` array don't transfer from `quoteItem` to `orderItem`.

How to make it work? Should I rather use some another way to set my custom data?
I thought about `product options` way, but I don't want to affect all the products, only particular ones.

Thanks.

Comment: add a new column to the `sales_flat_quote_item` table called `my_custom_data`.

Comment: Thanks, @Marius, is there another way to resolve the issue?

Comment: create another table that holds your value and a reference to the order item table.

Comment: I think it's too complicated and global. It should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attributes are set up correctly on both the `order_item` and the `quote_item` then you maybe missing the xml that copies the attribute value when you save and order.

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <your_attribute_code>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </your_attribute_code>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <your_attribute_code>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
        </your_attribute_code>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
```

This will copy the attribute value from quote item to order item when saving the order and also from order item to quote item when recreating a quote from an order via the admin or customer section.